# Yii2 "has no relation named" at search model even the function it is defined in the main model

Tags: php, yii2, relation, yii2-model

I am having a yii2 error : common\models\Book has no relation named "favorite".

When I try to add:

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = Book::find();
    $query->joinWith(['author', 'profile', 'favorite']);
```

In the book model I do have the public function:

```
public function getFavoritedIcon() {
    if (isset($this->favorite)) {
        return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk books-form"></i>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

And also this extra function to get the icon

```
public function getFavoritedIcon() {
    if (isset($this->favorite)) {
        return $icon;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

And this works fine in the grid where I want to add sorting and filter:

```
[
    'label' => 'Favorites',
    'attribute' => 'favorite',
    'value' => 'favoritedIcon',
    'hAlign' => 'center',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'width' => '50px',
],
```

I do some different things from another models I am using:

- in the grid i get the value as an icon from the book model but i used this before.
- the other thing is that the Favorite model has not the same name that the table but it work fine in the grid

abstract class Favorite extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {

```
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_favorite';
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id', 'book_id'], 'required'],
            [['user_id', 'book_id'], 'integer'],
            [['selectedTime'], 'safe']
        ];
    }
```

Any clues what I am doing wrong ?

======================================================

UPDATE after Pedro del Sol answer

There was some errors in the code but the main one was answered by Pedro,  I do had a favorite function in the Book model but not favorites with multiple output.

So now it is working like that:

In the Book model

```
    public function getFavorite() {
    $userID = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    return Favorite::find()->where(['user_id' => $userID, 'book_id' => $this->id])->one();
}

public function getFavorites() {
    $userID = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::className(), ['book_id' => 'id'], ['book_id' => $this->id]);
}
public function getFavoritedIcon() {
    if (isset($this->favorite)) {
        return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk books-form"></i>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

In the BookSearch model:

```
    public function search($params) {
    $query = Book::find();
    $query->joinWith(['favorites']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'title',
            'author_id',
            'rights_owner_id',
            'user_favorite.user_id',
        ]
    ]);
```

and the grid view :

```
        [
        'label' => 'Favorites',
        'attribute' => 'user_favorite.user_id',
        'value' => 'favoritedIcon',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'width' => '50px',
    ],
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having a method to `getFavoritedIcon()` is not the same as declaring a relation to `getFavorite()`

I assume that in your `Book` model class you have the methods `getAuthor()` and `getProfile()` which will return queries linking a `Book` with an `Author` and a `Profile`. You'll need something similar with `Favorite`(s) but I suspect the multiplicities will be different.

I think to declare your relation you'll need something like

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getFavorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::className(), ['book_id' => 'ID']);
}
```

if the relation between `Book`s and `Favorite`s is one to many (most likely) or

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getFavorite()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Favorite::className(), ['book_id' => 'ID']);
}
```

if the relation is one to one.

You can then use `joinWith()` with either 'favorite' or 'favorites' depending on the multiplicities of your relation.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, that was the main issue I updated my question based on your answer.